# Folder Path issues when requiring files

Tags: php

So, I followed a PHP OOP Tutorial on YouTube which was good, got me the code i needed, but now I'm trying to implement it into my site, and i'm having a bit of an error problem.

Here's my folder structure so you can see whats going on. The root folder 'modelawiki' is within my 'htdocs' folder within a XAMPP Localhost Server. I have other sites in other folders within my 'htdocs' folder. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrsx3.jpg

In my index.php file within my root folder (modelawiki), I'm requiring my 'core/init.php' file using the following code:

```
require_once 'core/init.php';
```

Which executes just fine. But when I move into my 'admin' folder and try to execute:

```
require_once '../core/init.php';
```

I'm coming up with the following error:

> Warning: require_once(functions/sanitize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/modelawiki/core/init.php on line 31
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'functions/sanitize.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/modelawiki/core/init.php on line 31

Heres my 'core/init.php' code:

```
// Auto Load Classes
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

// Load Functions
require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

How would I fix this issue in my 'core/init.php' file to be able to load from within the root folder, and any deeper folders within my folder tree? I also need to make sure that once I upload this to my Network Solutions FTP server that it will run as well.

Comment: where is located file core/init.php on your server ( complete path)?

Comment: /htdocs/modelawiki/core/init.php

Comment: and do you have a folder functions with sanitize.php inside it on your project root path?

Comment: Sanitize is: "htdocs/modelawiki/functions/sanitize.php"

Comment: as it is called inside core folder, try to move folder function inside core ( with file sanitize of course in it)

Comment: Same thing with the classes folder as well?

Comment: if classes folder is also inside, then just edit init.php with "../functions/sanitize.php";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use absolute paths instead:

1. get directory of root in your classloader

   ```
   // if called in core/init.php
   // the following will be the absolute path of whatever folder core is in
   $rootdir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
   ```
2. so from there you'll have something like this:

   ```
   $rootdir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));

   // Auto Load Classes
   spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
       require_once $rootdir . 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
   });

   // Load Functions
   require_once $rootdir . 'functions/sanitize.php';
   ```

Comment: You might want to add an additional '/' I am not sure if dirname will have that appended or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change init.php file as below. You have to give the path correctly.

require_once '../functions/sanitize.php';